# Can VS clean up repeated semicolons in C# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

Sometimes my I accidentally create a C# statement like this:

```
public void MyMethod() {
  DoStuff();;
}
```

When I run code cleanup on my solution, VS decides there should be a space between the statements and changes it to this:

```
public void MyMethod() {
  DoStuff(); ;
}
```

I would prefer that it just remove the extra semicolon. Obviously I can fix this by search and replace. But I'm wondering if there is a way to have the code cleanup do it.